# Confused and horrible at SC2. How does a noob go from bronze to GM?

Tags: starcraft-2

Bought the game 1 and a half months ago, stuck in bronze, 2nd position(win:50, lost: 58) but I'm horrible and don't know how to get better.

I'm using hotkeys, camera keys, constantly train scv, upgrade my units, expand but still get mega PWNED by all 3 races. My wins have generally consisted of leavers, players that freak out at a cloaked banshee and so on.

I don't have a build order. Also I feel that I don't know how to counter the units that my opponent has. Every time that I play, my army generally consists of upgraded marines..some marrauders, siege tanks and some medivacs but as I said, I get mega ultra pwned.

So, I know that this kind of question may be broad but any advices on how to get better?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry, dude, you're looking for a rather large book here.  That's not something we can help you with.  If you need help with a particular strategy, try asking about that.  That's something we should be able to help you with.

Comment: First step is to learn a basic build order. Your issue is probably that you're getting outmacroed heavily by an opponent who just makes more stuff than you. Here is a very basic Terran build order that's decent in all matchups: http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/1_Rax_FE_%28vs._Protoss%29

Comment: @icesilver I submitted an answer to another question about how to play Zerg. There are some basics there you can use. Otherwice, dont set GM as your goal now. Make silver your goal, then gold etc. And which server do you play on? I would like to see a replay of yours.

Comment: Please sign up to the more specific proposal here:  http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/58619/starcraft

Answer (score 1):

Getting to Grand Master takes a lot of time and practice. One could not just write up a quick way to get there because it requires a lot effort. Fortunately there are resources on the internet to guide you on your journey to Grand Master.

Sean Plott, aka Day[9], has a site called [Day9.tv](http://day9.tv/) that has something for everyone from the Bronze leaguer just starting out to more advanced strategies for the advanced player.

He runs or ran a stream on Tuesdays called [Newbie Tuesday's](http://day9.tv/archives/?q=%22Newbie%20Tuesday%22). Along with a **ton** of VoD's to watch. Day9's shows will start you on the fundamental's like Build Order's, what Macro and Micro is and how to improve your's. Everything you need to know that should at least get you out of Bronze.

Another thing you can try is in game there is a featured group named *Adopt A Newb*. The players in there are there volunteering their time helping anyone that needs it.

I hope that's enough to get you started. Best of luck on your road to Grand master.

Comment: "Go watch videos" isn't a very helpful answer at all.

Comment: @NieselClementine What? Fbueckert is correct, there isn't really an answer here. Telling someone to "Google" their answer is not an answer.

Comment: I'm pointing out *why* your answer is not useful.  That's the very definition of constructive.  You are free to expand it if you like, and, I'd like to point out, I'm much more conversant with Arqade's mores and standards than you are.  This answer does not meet those standards.

Comment: @NieselClementine you said a lot of stuff from a lot of places. Why you don't post HERE that information. you said "Google is your best friend" but, it should be "Arqade is your best friend" =) Create a complete and well formulated answer. You just gave an advice not an answer.

Comment: Broad and terrible questions will probably generate broad and terrible answers.  As far as this one goes, it's par for the course, really.  The question is pretty open ended, so there is no real way to answer it efficiently.

Comment: @NieselClementine People are allowed to vote as they wish. 8 people didn't like your answer, but 4 did (so far). Fbueckert was simply explaining his downvote... often, if downvoters don't do that, the person always asks "Why the downvotes?" This is a pretty clear example of why I think the people who think downvoters should be required to leave a comment are *wrong*. That said, we can all disagree with each other here and still be civil. If you think someone is being uncivil, either flag it for a mod to look at or simply don't engage. Escalating is not the correct choice.

Comment: Broad questions don't require any answers on this site, that's why we have a close reason for that. You were *primarily* pointing the asker at other resources - that is frowned upon, no matter the context.

Comment: @NieselClementine Go to the [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/) if you want to discuss this. the comment area is not suitable for this.

Comment: I apologize. I needed to re-read the rules. Please accept my apology for my actions. should i delete my answer?

Comment: @Niesel You had good intentions behind your answer and the advice you're giving here isn't incorrect, so I wouldn't remove it. If you feel so inclined, you could edit some links to resources that you think would be helpful into the answer to improve its utility.